# How do I solve that the mousover event overwrite popupopen event in Leaflet?

Tags: javascript, events, popup, leaflet, mouseover

I'm making a leaflet map where I'm trying to highlight a line layer when the mouse hovers over the line AND when the line displays a popup. When the popup isn't open the line should not be highlighted anymore (unless the mouse is hovering over it of course).

I have successfully managed to highlight the line when hovering by using the mouseover and mouseout events. I have also managed to highlight the line when it displays a popup by using the [popupopen](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.2.html#map-popupopen) and [popupclose](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.2.html#map-popupclose) events. However, the highlights only work when I use these events separately. As soon as I combine them and try to achieve the highlights at the same time, only the hovering highlight works. So it seems like the mouseover/mouseout events are overwriting the popupopen/popupclose events. *Does anyone have any idea why this is or how I can solve it?*

I have tried to call different functions for each event and to change the order of the events but it doesn't make any difference.

This is the code I have at the moment, which does not do what I want it to do. If the mouseover/mouseout events are removed, the highlights on the popupopen/popupclose events will show.

```
function allSubcommissionsHighlight(e) {
    e.target.setStyle({
        'color': '#00C5CD',
        'weight': 4,
        'opacity': 1
        });
    }
function allresetSubcommissionsHighlight(e) {
    e.target.setStyle({
        'color': '#256729',
        'weight': 2.5,
        'opacity': 0.5
        });
    }
function allSubcommissionsStyle(feature) {
                return {
                    "weight": 2.5,
                    "color": "#256729"
                };
            }
var allSubcommissions = new L.geoJson(null, {
    style: allSubcommissionsStyle,
        onEachFeature: function (feature, layer){
            if (feature.properties){
                var content = '<table id="infotable">' +
                              '<caption class="tablecaption">' + feature.properties.STATE + '</caption>' +
                              '<tr class="tabletr">' + '<th class="tableth">Submission</th>' + '<td class="tabletd">' + "<a href='" + feature.properties.Link + "'target='_blank'>" + feature.properties.ECS_ID_NUM + "</a>" + '</td>' + '</tr>' +
                              '<tr class="tabletr">' + '<th class="tableth">Status</th>' + '<td class="tabletd">' + feature.properties.STATUS + '</td>' + '</tr>' +
                              '<tr class="tabletr">' + '<th class="tableth">Committee</th>' + '<td class="tabletd"></td>' + '</tr>' +
                              '<tr class="tablenotr">' + '<th class="tablesubth">Chair</th>' + '<td class="tabletd">' + feature.properties.C + '</td>' + '</tr>' +
                              '<tr class="tablenotr">' + '<th class="tablesubth">Vice Chair(s)</th>' + '<td class="tabletd">' + feature.properties.VC + '</td>' + '</tr>' +
                              '<tr class="tablenotr">' + '<th class="tablesubth">Members</th>' + '<td class="tabletd">' + feature.properties.M + '</td>' + '</tr>' +
                              '<tr class="tabletr">' + '<th class="tableth">' + "<a href='" + feature.properties.Image + "'target='_blank'><img src='" + feature.properties.Image + "'width='" + "50" + "'length='" + "50" + "'/> </a>" + '</th>' + '<td class="tabletd">Click on the image to see it in full size</td>' + '</tr>' +
                              '<table>';
                    layer.bindPopup(content);

                    layer.on({
                        mouseover: allSubcommissionsHighlight,
                        mouseout: allresetSubcommissionsHighlight,
                        popupopen: allSubcommissionsHighlight,
                        popupclose: allresetSubcommissionsHighlight
                    });
            }
        }
});
$.getJSON('geojson/Subcommissions/all_Subcommissions.geojson', function (data) {
          allSubcommissions.addData(data);
});
```